# Java: Extending a Class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, super

I'm trying to extend my Vehicle class to a HumanPowered class -- Has a field for calories per hour. This is my first time trying to extend a class so I'm a bit confused here.

```
class Vehicle
{
String description;
String idNumber;
int numWheels;

public Vehicle(String aDescription, String aIdNumber, int aNumWheels)
{
    description = aDescription;
    idNumber = aIdNumber;
    numWheels = aNumWheels;
}
void setDescription (String aDescription)
{
    description = aDescription;
}
void setIdNumber (String aIdNumber)
{
    idNumber = aIdNumber;
}
void setNumWheels (int aNumWheels)
{
    numWheels = aNumWheels;
}
public String getDescription()
{
    return description;
}
public String getIdNumber()
{
    return idNumber;
}
public int getNumWheels()
{
    return numWheels;
}
public String toString()
{
    String result= String.format("ID: %s Description: %s Wheels: %d",idNumber,description,numWheels);
    return result;
}

}
class humanPowered extends Vehicle
{
int calories;
public humanPowered(String aDescription, String aIdNumber, int aNumWheels, int aCalories) //Error here
{
    description = aDescription;
    idNumber = aIdNumber;
    numWheels = aNumWheels;
    calories = aCalories;   
}
void setCalories (int aCalories)
{
    calories = aCalories;
}
public int getCalories()
{
    return calories;
}
public String toString()
{
    String result= String.format("ID: %s Description: %s Wheels: %d Calories per Hour: %d",idNumber,description,numWheels, calories);
    return result;
}
}
```

I'm getting an error marked above on my constructor for my humanPowered class saying "Implicit super constructor Vehicle() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor." I can't figure out where I'm going wrong here. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Copy the complete error message, paste it into google, click on the first result you get. There you go, you have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vehicle` don't have default constructor hence you have to call its constructor form `humanPowered` class passing required arguments at the first line of its constructor.

```
public humanPowered(String aDescription, String aIdNumber, int aNumWheels, int aCalories)    
{
   super(aDescription,aIdNumber,aNumWheels);
   ...//other code
}
```

Points to remember:

- Every class have default constructor that is no-argument constructor
- If class creates a constructor passing arguments then by default constructor is not created
- Each constructor by default calls default constructor of its super-class